# Update pointer to last node in linked list

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I'm working with a doubly linked list and I want to use a pointer that points to the last node in the list, so I can start traversing from the end. As you can see by my code for the insert function, I go through the entire linked list at the end to set the last pointer. Is there a better way to do this? I feel like I might be wasting resources using this method.

```
void LinkedList::insert(ElementType dataVal, int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index > mySize)
    {
        cerr << "Illegal location to insert -- " << index << endl;
        return;
    }

    Node * newPtr = new Node(dataVal);
    Node * predPtr = first;

    if (index == 0)
    {
        newPtr->next = first;
        first = newPtr;

        if(newPtr->next != NULL){
            predPtr->next->prev = newPtr;
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < index; i++)
            predPtr = predPtr->next;

        newPtr->prev = predPtr;
        newPtr->next = predPtr->next;
        if(newPtr->next != NULL){
            predPtr->next->prev = newPtr;
        } 
        predPtr->next = newPtr;
    } 
    mySize++;
    Node * lastPtr = first;

    while(lastPtr->next != NULL){
        lastPtr = lastPtr->next;
    }
    last = lastPtr;
}
```

Comment: In general, you set `head->next = tail` and `tail->prev = head` when you create the list.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Do I do that in the constructor or in this function?

Comment: Instead of iterating over entire list to set last pointer check index of element to be inserted.If it is at the end just point the last pointer to the new pointer else leave last pointer as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just keep the 'last' pointer without refind it from first?
There are two conditions:

1. The new added node is in front of the last node, in this case, 'last' still points to the last node.
2. The new added node is the new last node, in this case, 'last' will be the new added node. So you just need to move 'last' to its next.

Just change the last few lines to:

```
while(last->next != NULL) {
    last = last->next;
}
```

Update:

Consider the case where adding the first node, you should change the last few lines to:

```
if (last == NULL) {
    last = first;
}
if (last->next != NULL) {
    last = last->next;
}
```

Comment: If I do that then where do I initially set last?

Comment: Initialize 'last' like variable 'first' in the constructor as you used in your code.